# Is there any java library to convert / parse ODF to html output?

Tags: java, for-loop, odf

I need to convert ODF document to html. Is there any java library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking in http://odftoolkit.org/?

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but I will look into this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have found a converter here: http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter. 
I have not yet tried this, will this be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

http://odt2html.gradsoft.ua/Odt2Html.html